# image IBOutlets - swift language

Tags: ios, image, swift

I am pretty new to this world and I having problem understanding something related to `IBOutlets`.

I cannot find the right code line to write when declaring the `IBOutlet` (in this case a image) into the `IBAction` button.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var zombieBtn: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func colorBtn() {
        zombieBtn.image
    }
}
```

In the `zombieBtn.image` i cannot complete it to call the image from `zombieBtn`

Comment: Are you trying to set the zombieBtn image, or are you trying to get the zombieBtn image, or something else?

Comment: Is `zombieBtn` a `UIButton` or a `UIImageView`? If it's the former then why are you saying it's a `UIImageView` in the property? If it's the latter then why are you calling it a button? Call it `zombieImageView` instead. Make things easy for yourself.